# Isolating Zend_Session in PHPUnit tests

Tags: php, phpunit, zend-auth, zend-session

I am testing authentification functionality of my site. Zend_Auth is using as authorization engine. But auth status remains between tests and I need to write 'logout' in every tearDown.

Now everything is all right. But the problem is following. As for I know Zend_Auth uses Zend_Session for storing auth data. So, session is common for all tests. I am affraid that in future it can cause problems.

Can you tell me what is the best practice to make sessions for each test isolated?

Now I can imagine only manually starting session in setUp and stop in tearDown. But I have many tests and implementing this can take a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

PHPUnit allows you to [define a shared fixture](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/fixtures.html#fixtures.sharing-fixture) (a common set up) for a whole test suite. However, this solution just masks a flaw in the design of the tests, since it doesn't address their dependency on a common global state. A better solution is to [use test doubles](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html), creating custom stubs of certain classes to control the behaviour of chosen parts of the system.

In this case you could try to create a stub of Zend_Auth so that it skips the use of Zend_Session and returns the desired permissions for each unit test.

Comment: But in both cases I still need to make changes in all my existed tests. And I am looking for some way not to do it. If it is possible.

Comment: The question was: Can you tell me what is the best practice to make sessions for each test isolated? Well, these are a couple of options. On the other hand, implementing a shared fixture doesn't really require many changes, you only need to create a test suite for all those tests requiring session authentication and move the fixtures from the tests to a common one in the suite.
There's still another option, which is to create a mock of Zend_Auth for testing purposes only. Then it's just a matter of find and replace.

Comment: Hi there, I recalled yet another approach that may work for you (fake the user identity), please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937387/is-there-any-way-to-force-authentication-with-zend-auth/2939327#2939327